# Python solving patterns and returning answers with digits and english words

Tags: python, loops

I am incredibly confused. I am trying to make a program that follows a pattern this pattern being:

```
Index:    Value:
0         0
1         10
2         1110
3         3110
4         132110
5         1113122110
6         311311222110
...
```

This pattern takes the previous value of the function and says the number of digits for example
if index 1 is 10, 2 will say one one and one zero or 1110.

I made a function that takes the first character of a string and returns how many times that character appears in the rest of the string. I need to make a prompt for index and it will then print out:

```
index : digits : english words
 3 : 3110 : three ones. one zero
```

This is the code I have so far but I can't figure out how to solve for the actual value:

```
def strHead(s):
   """strHead: String -> String"""
   return s[0]

def strTail(s, run):
  """strTail: String -> String"""
   return s[1:]

def runLenAux(s, c):
""" s = string and c = head of string
"""
    if s == "":
        return 0
    else:
        if strHead(s)== c:
            return 1 + int(runLenAux(strTail(s), c))
        else:
            return 0
```

EDIT:
Unfortunately I cannot use any built in function like .append or len() I can't even use a list. :( Is there a way of incorporating my function runLenAux(s, c) into finding the value if given an index?

Comment: Note that your `strTail` returns a copy of the entire string `s`.  To return the tail of `s` (everything except the first character), use `s[1:]`.

Answer (score 3):

This has mostly been written for you in the form of `itertools.groupby` which takes an iterable (in your case, the string) and groups unique elements.  It gives a generator (think of it as a list that you can loop through, if you're not familiar with them) of pairs, where each pair is the value from your original iterable, and then all those values.

So, for example:

```py
>>> s = str(1113122110)
>>> groupby(s)
<itertools.groupby at 0x1044be5d0>
```

Let's make them lists to see them all:

```py
>>> [(n, list(c)) for n, c in groupby(s)]
[('1', ['1', '1', '1']),
 ('3', ['3']),
 ('1', ['1']),
 ('2', ['2', '2']),
 ('1', ['1', '1']),
 ('0', ['0'])]
```

To get this into the format you want, you really want the length of each of the secondary lists:

```py
>>> [(len(list(c)), n) for n, c in groupby(s)]
[(3, '1'), (1, '3'), (1, '1'), (2, '2'), (2, '1'), (1, '0')]
```

Let's make the lengths strings:

```py
>>> [(str(len(list(c))), n) for n, c in groupby(s)]
[('3', '1'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('2', '1'), ('1', '0')]
```

To get the next number, you'll want to `join` all these.  To do this, 'chain' them:

```py
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> ''.join(chain(*[(str(len(list(c))), n) for n, c in groupby(s)]))
'311311222110'
```

Of course, you probably want an integer at the end if you don't want to just print it:

```py
>>> int(''.join(chain(*[(str(len(list(c))), n) for n, c in groupby(s)])))
311311222110
```

To get the english descriptor, I'd use a dict to get the english words:

```py
nwords = {'0': zero, '1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'three'} # etc.
for c, n in [(str(len(list(c))), n) for n, c in groupby(s)]:
    print "{c} {n}{p}".format(p='' if c=='1' else 's', c=nwords[c], n=nwords[n])
```

which prints:

```py
three ones
one three
one one
two twos
two ones
one zero
```

I'll leave it to you to put these parts together to get something that takes an index and recursively counts previous answers to give the final answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, these:

```
def strHead(s):
   """strHead: String -> String"""
   return s[0]

def strTail(s, run):
  """strTail: String -> String"""
   return s[:]
```

They don't do anything useful; the first returns item 0 and the second just returns the string. Chuck 'em.

Then

```
def runLenAux(s, c):
    if s == "":
        return 0
    else:
        if strHead(s)== c:
            return 1 + int(runLenAux(strTail(s), c))
        else:
            return 0
```

Now there's an obvious problem. You're treating these like numbers when they are at best *lists* of numbers. But then other times you're treating them like strings.

Let's treat them like lists because it's more obvious that way.

So:

```
def runLenAux(s, c):
```

What are `s` and `c`? Dunno. I imagine this is meant to get the next value, so do a `[1, 0] → [1, 1, 1, 0]` mapping. So let it take one list:

```
def look_and_say(term):
    """Looks at and says a term."""
```

Instead of doing your funny `->` stuff, in Python 3 you can annotate your function. Impress your peers by showing them this semi-obsure fact!

```
def look_and_say(term: "[int]") -> "[int]":
    """Looks at and says a term."""
```

Here I use `"[int]"` to mean "a `list` of `int`s".

So, on to the next part:

```
    if s == "":
        return 0
```

Gosh! Are you planning on using recursion?! That's too much! We're not [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell) over here!

OK, from the top. We want to iterate through, keeping count of how many of the same item we have seen, yes? So we could do a loop like:

```
for item in term:
    count how many are the same
    if different, break
```

(It sounds like something that's been done before. Well, it has. It's called `itertools.groupby`. Let's pretend you didn't know that, though.)

```
count = 0
match = None
for item in term:
    # If this isn't the same we should stop counting
    if match != item:
        do_something_with_count_and_match

        # Start again from this item
        count = 1
        match = item

    # If this is the same we should continue counting
    else:
        count = count + 1
```

That looks good!

What to put for `do_something_with_count_and_match`? Well, let's keep a list to put things in and chuck our result in there

```
# This is what we're building
next_term = []

...
for item in term:
    ...
    if match != item:
        # Say "One One" or "Two Threes" or "Three Ones", etc.
        next_term.append(count)
        next_term.append(match)

        # Start again from this item
        count = 1
        match = item
    ...
```

So, does it run?

```
def look_and_say(term: "[int]") -> "[int]":
    """Looks at and says a term."""
    # This is what we're building
    next_term = []

    count = 0
    match = None
    for item in term:
        # If this isn't the same we should stop counting
        if match != item:
            # Say "One One" or "Two Threes" or "Three Ones", etc.
            next_term.append(count)
            next_term.append(match)

            # Start again from this item
            count = 1
            match = item

        # If this is the same we should continue counting
        else:
            count = count + 1

look_and_say([0])
#>>>
```

Hmm... No output.

Ah, we forgot to `return` the `next_term`:

```
def look_and_say(term: "[int]") -> "[int]":
    ... # All that stuff

    return next_term

look_and_say([0])
#>>> [0, None]
```

Hmm.. Well that's no good. We need to make sure we aren't counting the `None` placeholder for `match`:

```
def look_and_say(term: "[int]") -> "[int]":
    ...
    for item in term:
        ...
        if match != item:
            if match is not None:
                next_term.append(count)
                next_term.append(match)
            ...
    ...
```

And we also need to add the last section even though it won't trigger the `else` (the loop will stop):

```
def look_and_say(term: "[int]") -> "[int]":
    ...
    for item in term:
        ...

    if match != item:
        if match is not None:
            next_term.append(count)
            next_term.append(match)

    return next_term
```

Then try it:

```
def look_and_say(term: "[int]") -> "[int]":
    """Looks at and says a term."""
    # This is what we're building
    next_term = []

    count = 0
    match = None
    for item in term:
        # If this isn't the same we should stop counting
        if match != item:
            # Say "One One" or "Two Threes" or "Three Ones", etc.
            if match is not None:
                next_term.append(count)
                next_term.append(match)

            # Start again from this item
            count = 1
            match = item

        # If this is the same we should continue counting
        else:
            count = count + 1

    if match is not None:
        next_term.append(count)
        next_term.append(match)

    return next_term

look_and_say([0])
#>>> [1, 0]

look_and_say([1, 0])
#>>> [1, 1, 1, 0]

look_and_say([1, 1, 1, 0])
#>>> [3, 1, 1, 0]
```

Yeah!

I did it like this to show you that programming isn't a magic trick. You just need to keep trying and applying what you know.

Personally I'd implement it like this:

```
from itertools import groupby

# What we just implemented
def look_and_say(string):
    for k, v in groupby(string):
        yield sum(1 for _ in v)
        yield k

list(look_and_say([0]))
#>>> [1, 0]

list(look_and_say([1, 0]))
#>>> [1, 1, 1, 0]

list(look_and_say([1, 1, 1, 0]))
#>>> [3, 1, 1, 0]
```

But that's just 'cause I knew about `groupby`.

Answer (score 1):

while itertools.groupby() makes it easy, sometimes it's fun to hack something together

```
def foo(seed = '0', nbr_of_indexes = 6):
    """returns a formatted string matching pattern described by OP
    """
    def groups(s, match = None, count = 0, result = ''):
        """count consecutive matches

        returns str
        """
        # recursion base case, no more s
        if not s:
            result += (str(count) + match)
            return result
        # initialize match
        if not match:
            match = s[0]
        if s[0] == match:
            count += 1
        else:
            result += (str(count) + match)
            match = s[0]
            count = 1
        return groups(s[1:], match, count, result)
    result = [(0,'0')]
    for index in xrange(1, nbr_of_indexes + 1):
        result.append((index, groups(seed)))
        seed = result[-1][1]
    return ''.join(['{}\t{}\n'.format(*thing) for thing in result])    

>>> print foo()
0   0
1   10
2   1110
3   3110
4   132110
5   1113122110
6   311311222110

>>>
```

**edit**: changed groups() to group and count the whole string instead of just the first item

Comment: Is there a way to not use the the append function?

Comment: Append is a list object method not a function. The code can be rewritten without it.

Comment: Is there a way of making it without using a list?

Comment: yes.  you could use the return _value_ of groups() in any number of ways.  This problem seems awfully familiar to me, i wonder why.  it is best that you figure out how groups() works - it could be used as a _stand-alone_ function.